# Don't Starve "select (originally right mouse)" and "left" are bound to A

Tags: steam, dont-starve

My steam game don't starve has the action that "right mouse" would usually do is bound to a and move left is also bound to a. I tried deleting all my don't starve files and i cant find the right bind command to bind right mouse to its original action. I haven't played the game in over a year. PLEASE HELP!!!